# Alinear dos elementos en la misma fila

Tags: c#, imagen, xamarin

Tengo dos elementos que quiero ubicar en la misma fila pero uno se come el espacio del otro. Estoy usando *Xamarin*. Tengo que hacer que se vea como en la primera imagen, pero se ve como en la segunda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`

```
            <FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" AlignItems="Center">
                <Label FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" FontSize="17" Text="Title"/>                  
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" WidthRequest="15" HeightRequest="15">
                <Label Text="mm/dd/yy"/>
                <Image WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="24" Source="back.png"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </FlexLayout>
            <FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" AlignItems="Center">
                <Label TextColor="#667085" FontSize="17" Text="No había nada en el cielo estrellado esa noche, que hicieran sospechar las cosas extrañas y misteriosas que irían a suceder pronto."/>
            </FlexLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>  `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primera vista diría que el problema es fijar el WidthRequest y HightRequest en el StackLayout, prueba algo así:

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" AlignItems="Center">
   <Label FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" FontSize="17" Text="Title"/>
   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="mm/dd/yy"/>
                <Image WidthRequest="18" HeightRequest="24" Source="back.png"/>
   </StackLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

Espero que funcione.